Display last date of training for a month
I am working with a new reporting system. I am creating a report to show training that was completed in each month by category. I have gotten the report to the point that I get my participants and dates, but I can only get it to count the number of hours per month. Is there a way to just show that last day that a class was taken in a month? I am assuming its the SUM but I cannot seem to locate the proper syntax to just show the day of the month as the value.

SELECT
    "t4"."Attendee_Name__Last__First_Middle_Suffix_" AS "Attendee_Name__Last__First_Middle_Suffix__res",
    "t4"."datetime_months_Class_Sessions_Session_Start_Date" AS "datetime_months_Class_Sessions_Session_Start_Date_res",
    SUM("t4"."Hours") AS "sum__Hours_res"
FROM
    (SELECT
         "t3"."Attendee_Name__Last__First_Middle_Suffix_",
         DATE_TRUNC('MONTH', "t2"."Session_Start_Date") AS "datetime_months_Class_Sessions_Session_Start_Date",
         "t0"."Hours"
     FROM
         (SELECT
              "_CLASSSESSIONID_PART1",
              "_CLASSSESSIONID_PART2",
              "Hours",
              "Credit Name" AS "Credit_Name"
          FROM
              "PM_CLASSES"."Class Session Credits"
          WHERE
              "Credit Name" = 'FAR 139 CATEGORY 1 - AIRPORT FAMILIARIZATION') AS "t0"
     INNER JOIN 
         ((SELECT
               "_CLASSSESSIONID_PART1",
               "_CLASSSESSIONID_PART2",
               "Session Start Date" AS "Session_Start_Date"
           FROM
               "PM_CLASSES"."Class Sessions"
           WHERE
               "Session Start Date" >= '2023-04-10 00:00:00'
               AND "Session Start Date" < '2024-04-04 00:00:00') AS "t2" 
     INNER JOIN 
         (SELECT
              "_CLASSSESSIONID_PART1",
              "_CLASSSESSIONID_PART2",
              "Attendee Name (Last, First Middle Suffix)" AS "Attendee_Name__Last__First_Middle_Suffix_"
          FROM
              "PM_CLASSES"."Class Session Attendees") AS "t3" ON "t2"."_CLASSSESSIONID_PART1" = "t3"."_CLASSSESSIONID_PART1"
        AND "t2"."_CLASSSESSIONID_PART2" = "t3"."_CLASSSESSIONID_PART2"
      ) ON "t0"."_CLASSSESSIONID_PART1" = "t2"."_CLASSSESSIONID_PART1"
      AND "t0"."_CLASSSESSIONID_PART2" = "t2"."_CLASSSESSIONID_PART2"
    ) AS "t4"
GROUP BY
    "t4"."Attendee_Name__Last__First_Middle_Suffix_",
    "t4"."datetime_months_Class_Sessions_Session_Start_Date"
ORDER BY
    "t4"."Attendee_Name__Last__First_Middle_Suffix_",    
    "t4"."datetime_months_Class_Sessions_Session_Start_Date"

So far I have broken the report several times but am successful with getting to give me the total hours per month. I have looked through other posts but cannot seem to locate a suitable solution.


I am assuming its the SUM

This is incorrect, if you want the last of a field then your general options are MAX/MIN or to sort the set and take the first response.
In this case, you are already grouping by month, so we should be able to take the `MAX(Session_Start_Date)' in the group, but you will need to expose this to make it available:
SELECT
    "t4"."Attendee_Name__Last__First_Middle_Suffix_" AS "Attendee_Name__Last__First_Middle_Suffix__res",
    "t4"."datetime_months_Class_Sessions_Session_Start_Date" AS "datetime_months_Class_Sessions_Session_Start_Date_res",
    SUM("t4"."Hours") AS "sum__Hours_res",
    MAX("t4"."Session_Start_Date") as "Last_Session_Start_Date"
FROM
    (SELECT
         "t3"."Attendee_Name__Last__First_Middle_Suffix_",
         DATE_TRUNC('MONTH', "t2"."Session_Start_Date") AS "datetime_months_Class_Sessions_Session_Start_Date",
         "t0"."Hours",
         "t2"."Session_Start_Date"
     FROM
         (SELECT
              "_CLASSSESSIONID_PART1",
              "_CLASSSESSIONID_PART2",
              "Hours",
              "Credit Name" AS "Credit_Name"
          FROM
              "PM_CLASSES"."Class Session Credits"
          WHERE
              "Credit Name" = 'FAR 139 CATEGORY 1 - AIRPORT FAMILIARIZATION') AS "t0"
     INNER JOIN 
         ((SELECT
               "_CLASSSESSIONID_PART1",
               "_CLASSSESSIONID_PART2",
               "Session Start Date" AS "Session_Start_Date"
           FROM
               "PM_CLASSES"."Class Sessions"
           WHERE
               "Session Start Date" >= '2023-04-10 00:00:00'
               AND "Session Start Date" < '2024-04-04 00:00:00') AS "t2" 
     INNER JOIN 
         (SELECT
              "_CLASSSESSIONID_PART1",
              "_CLASSSESSIONID_PART2",
              "Attendee Name (Last, First Middle Suffix)" AS "Attendee_Name__Last__First_Middle_Suffix_"
          FROM
              "PM_CLASSES"."Class Session Attendees") AS "t3" ON "t2"."_CLASSSESSIONID_PART1" = "t3"."_CLASSSESSIONID_PART1"
        AND "t2"."_CLASSSESSIONID_PART2" = "t3"."_CLASSSESSIONID_PART2"
      ) ON "t0"."_CLASSSESSIONID_PART1" = "t2"."_CLASSSESSIONID_PART1"
      AND "t0"."_CLASSSESSIONID_PART2" = "t2"."_CLASSSESSIONID_PART2"
    ) AS "t4"
GROUP BY
    "t4"."Attendee_Name__Last__First_Middle_Suffix_",
    "t4"."datetime_months_Class_Sessions_Session_Start_Date"
ORDER BY
    "t4"."Attendee_Name__Last__First_Middle_Suffix_",    
    "t4"."datetime_months_Class_Sessions_Session_Start_Date"


quick note: using arbitrary aliases for your sub tables make this logic hard to interpret, consider using meaningful names.

I have deliberately not formatted the datetime value in SQL, ideally this would be implemented in the reporting later or report definition, not the SQL itself.


